# No response of nginx after installing phusion passenger nginx module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, phusion

I installed phusionpassenger nginx module . And I had to choose the nginx source path to make it go .  But after the whole process .

When In My Terminal I type :

```
sudo service nginx start
```

or,

```
nginx -s signal
```

it doesn't work , But it is there in /opt/nginx path.

Again the message I am getting is :

```
The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages:
* nginx-core
* nginx-extras
* nginx-full
* nginx-light
* nginx-naxsi
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

so , what should I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

You see this message because passenger doesn't install init.d script for start/stop nginx. You should create it manually. I am using such [nginx](https://gist.github.com/maxd/5231120) init.d script.